# Use custom webclient in Spring webflux integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I am building a webclient with custom exchangefilter. This custom exchangefilter use reselience4j for load balancing stuff. I want to add webflux spring integration outbound gateway to send request and receive http response. Is there a way i can inject my custom webclient in spring webflux integration without impacting the functionality of exchangefilter?

Answer (score 1):

The gateway has several constructors that take a `WebClient`.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/2217cb4f90a722fdfd5868cfc376809b7eb7da31/spring-integration-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/webflux/outbound/WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java#L103-L116

e.g.

```java
/**
 * Create a handler that will send requests to the provided URI using a provided WebClient.
 * @param uri The URI.
 * @param webClient The WebClient to use.
 */
public WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler(String uri, @Nullable WebClient webClient) {
```

And, with the DSL

```java
        .handle(WebFlux.outboundGateway(uri, webCLient))
        . ...
        .get();
```

Comment: Thanks Garry!! Is there any end to end example to implement outbound gateway for webflux integration?